# Sending Email For cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp

in controller :

```
<?php 

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class MessagesController extends AppController
{
    public $uses = array();

    public function send()
    {
        if (!empty($this->request->data) )
        {
            $email = new CakeEmail();
            $email->from(array('jerold@ballo.com.ph' => 'Jerold Ballo'));
            $email->to($this->Email->data['to']);
            $email->subject($this->Email->data['subject']);
            if ($email->send($this->Email->data['message'])) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Email From me'), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and i got this

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method App::uses() in C:\xampp\htdocs\reservation\controllers\messages_controller.php on line 3`

Please Help me....

Comment: mate, you are using CakePHP 1.3 framework , but your code is using CakePHP 2.x. Please check the correct Book. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Email.html

Comment: can u guide me where to put those codes? newbie here...

Answer (score 1):

Remove `App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');`

Try

```
class MessagesController extends AppController
{
    public $components = array('Email');
    ...
```

You can now use $this->Email the way you have it in the code