# Send Email using cakephp 1.3

Tags: email, cakephp-1.3

im using the code of this reference
http://books.google.com.ph/books?id=oXpiVSW5jqkC&pg=PT576&lpg=PT576&dq=app/views/elements/email/html&source=bl&ots=hAf3uDnVRb&sig=rrlbwekcKWfKhvmCvlYdFqC4EHQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dVnfUpbdB_GziQfSh4HgCA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=app%2Fviews%2Felements%2Femail%2Fhtml&f=false

i wrote the codes in my appcontroller in my emails_controller
<

lass EmailsController extends AppController {

```
public $components = array(
    'Email' =>array(
    'delivery' => 'smpt',
    'smtpOptions' => array(
    'host' =>
    'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'redbaloons@gmail.com',
    'password' => '123456789'
    )
    )
    );
```

then after that i follow this to controllers index()
var $name = 'Emails';

```
function index() {
    $this->Email->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('emails', $this->paginate());
    $this->Email->to = 'Destination<redbaloons@gmail.com>';
    $this->Email->subject = 'Testing The Email component';
    $sent('Hello World');
    if(!$sent) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $this->Email->smtpError . '<br />';
    }else{
        echo 'Email sent!';
}
```

then just test it, then i got this error
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\reservation\controllers\emails_controller.php on line 24

any configuration just to test this?? Please Help...

Comment: Which line is line 24?

Comment: $sent('Hello World');

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending Email For cakephp 1.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273763/sending-email-for-cakephp-1-3)

Comment: atal error: Call to undefined method EmailComponent::create() in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\controllers\emails_controller.php on line 51

Comment: in my email/views<<<<<<<function add() {
  if (!empty($this->data)) {
   $this->Email->create();
   $this->Email->send('Hello');
   if ($this->Email->save($this->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The email has been saved', true));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The email could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong in this line:

```
$sent('Hello World');
```

I don't know exactly what you should be using, but it should be something like:

```
$sent = $this->Email->send("Hello World");
```

Comment: tnx for that theirs no fatal error but i got this \Undefined property: Email::$smtpError [APP\controllers\emails_controller.php, line 26]